Batch computation of similarity matrices of different sizes (Pytorch)
I am computing node features of dimension D for a B different graphs where the graph i has N_i nodes, hence I have a batch representation as a tensor of dimension (N_1 + ... + N_B)xD. I want to compute the similarity of each node to each other within the same graph, if X_i is the node features of graph i (of dimension N_i x D), I need to compute X_i@X_i.T (dimension N_i x D) for each i.
Afterwards, I will compute a the cross entropy loss between X_i@X_i.T and Id_{N_i}.
I need to have a fast way to compute this loss for a batch (batch size of 100) in parallel and on the GPU (with Pytorch and Pytorch Geometric). I already tried to reduce the batch size to one and to pad the tensors so that the batch can be reshaped into B x N_max x F, however, the batch size of 1 is way to slow and padding the tensors doesn't work because torch_geometric expect contiguous tensors for the message passing part to compute the node features.

Consider taking the similarity of the whole batch and masked out the similarity between nodes of different graphs. The easiest way to construct such mask is to first create a vector and then do a equal operator like this:
batch_vector = torch.cat([[1]*N_1, [2]*N_2, ..., [B]*N_B], dim = 0) # shape (N_1 + ... + N_B,)

mask = batch_vector.unsqueeze(0) == batch_vector.unsqueeze(1) # shape (N_1 + ... + N_B, N_1 + ... + N_B)

This would not be memory efficient though, so that's a trade-off.

Thank you for your answer, however this approach will not work in my case as the added computation will be to big. Computing the similarity matrix of the batch will multiply my time and memory complexity by batch_size which is not feasible in my case (batch_size = 100).
